# Three way switch replacement

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

Replacing switch as in pic. Old Switch has no black terminal screw. How do I tell which is the common wire? Red is typically traveler wire but  It has the white wire connected to terminal as well which I don’t think is common?  [image]

Comment: Search the switch for markings, then. That picture is too underexposed to correct in Photoshop, I tried.

Comment: No not really at all

Comment: [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/109904/34147) to the linked question above should tell you how to determine which is the common.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-contact voltage tester like [this Klein from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3O3EN4b):

[image: Klein NCVT1]

See which wires are live in various switch positions. Typically you will have either:

- One wire always hot = incoming hot
- The other wires alternate depending on switch position = travellers

or

- One wire hot only when the light is on = switched hot
- The other wires alternate depending on the *other* switch's position = travellers

If *everything* lights up an NCVT all the time (except when the breaker is off) then you'll need to test with a multimeter. Some NCVTs are more sensitive than others to phantom/induced voltage.

Comment: they'll all show as hot.  phantom voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tell which wire is what on a switch is to kill the power to the switch (turn off the breaker for the switch) and use a continuity tester on the wires contacts.  The two travelers will be disconnected from each other no matter which position the switch is in.